# Export IPA from Xcode for re-signing with another's distribution certificate

Tags: ios, app-store, xcode10.1

I am using my own developer account created App ID (let's say com.developer.myapp) with App Groups and Keychain sharing enabled for development. My organisation uses its own account to upload apps on AppStore. The problem is, they have not shared distribution certificate along with provisioning profiles with me. I have asked the team to enable App Groups and Keychain sharing for company's app id (com.mycompany.finalproduct). Now, I need to export IPA from Xcode by 'iOS AppStore' method of distribution but I am facing errors while doing so.

1. Kept 2 entitlements for development and distribution since app groups are different
2. Since distribution cert is not with me, I am thrown an error saying app group doesn't match while trying to archive in release mode
3. Removed 'Code Signing Identity' for Release mode in 'Build Settings'
4. Archived in debug mode, validation passed and IPA sent for re-signing
5. App re-signed with distribution cert but when uploading to AppStore Connect, error "The SwiftSupport folder is missing. Rebuild your app using the current public (GM) version of Xcode and resubmit it."

Answer (score 1):

The SwiftSupport folder will only be added on "Store Export" when exporting with xCode. If you do not have a distribution certificate for the store, you cannot export it this way.

If you just switch the signing on a developer IPA, the folder is still missing. There are several threads about this topic here. Adding the folder manually to the IPA will also not work pretty well. Maybe there exists some workarounds out there, but this in my eyes not the right way.

We also have customers, that only give us a developer certificate and provisioning profile dedicated to this, *but with the final app id*. **In the past we always gave them the .xcarchive, so they can export/upload the IPA on their own.** And that is, in my eyes the way it should be.
Now they want us to upload the IPA to a third party tool, but this tool also checks the IPA for the SwiftSupport folder for Store Apps, so we cannot upload the IPA.

In my opinion it is not the external developers task to take care about this, if he just gets the developer cert. and profile. I can totally understand the customer doesn't want to hand out a distribution certificate to external sources, but then he must accept, that he needs to make the final step on his own.

Comment: What if you did the following?: 
1) build the app with a bundle id an appstore certificate and provisioning profile of your own 
2) resign the appstore ipa with a p12 and provisioning profile from your client. 
In theory the client wouldn't need to add you to their apple dev team, just hand you the certs and profiles. For resign I use this: https://docs.fastlane.tools/actions/resign/

Comment: @pampanet This is exactly what we/the customer is currently doing. We add our app with one of our own certificates and store profiles to the customers tool, and he is resigning it automatically after upload.